# Sign in Twitter OAuth without Sessions aka token_secret (AngularJS Fail)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, oauth, twitter-oauth

This is an express route from [angularjs satellizer example](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/node/server.js#L571), implementing 3 legged OAuth with Twitter:

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Login with Twitter
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
app.get('/auth/twitter', function(req, res) {
  var requestTokenUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
  var accessTokenUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token';
  var authenticateUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate';

  if (!req.query.oauth_token || !req.query.oauth_verifier) {
    var requestTokenOauth = {
      consumer_key: config.TWITTER_KEY,
      consumer_secret: config.TWITTER_SECRET,
      callback: config.TWITTER_CALLBACK
    };

    // Step 1. Obtain request token for the authorization popup.
    request.post({ url: requestTokenUrl, oauth: requestTokenOauth }, function(err, response, body) {
      var oauthToken = qs.parse(body);
      var params = qs.stringify({ oauth_token: oauthToken.oauth_token });

      // Step 2. Redirect to the authorization screen.
      res.redirect(authenticateUrl + '?' + params);
    });
  } else {
    var accessTokenOauth = {
      consumer_key: config.TWITTER_KEY,
      consumer_secret: config.TWITTER_SECRET,
      token: req.query.oauth_token,
      verifier: req.query.oauth_verifier
    };

    // Step 3. Exchange oauth token and oauth verifier for access token.
    request.post({ url: accessTokenUrl, oauth: accessTokenOauth }, function(err, response, profile) {
      profile = qs.parse(profile);

      // Step 4a. Link user accounts.
      if (req.headers.authorization) {
        User.findOne({ twitter: profile.user_id }, function(err, existingUser) {
          if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(409).send({ message: 'There is already a Twitter account that belongs to you' });
          }
          var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
          var payload = jwt.decode(token, config.TOKEN_SECRET);
          User.findById(payload.sub, function(err, user) {
            if (!user) {
              return res.status(400).send({ message: 'User not found' });
            }
            user.twitter = profile.user_id;
            user.displayName = user.displayName || profile.screen_name;
            user.save(function(err) {
              res.send({ token: createToken(user) });
            });
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Step 4b. Create a new user account or return an existing one.
        User.findOne({ twitter: profile.user_id }, function(err, existingUser) {
          if (existingUser) {
            var token = createToken(existingUser);
            return res.send({ token: token });
          }
          var user = new User();
          user.twitter = profile.user_id;
          user.displayName = profile.screen_name;
          user.save(function() {
            var token = createToken(user);
            res.send({ token: token });
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The problem is Step 3:

```
   var accessTokenOauth = {
      consumer_key: config.TWITTER_KEY,
      consumer_secret: config.TWITTER_SECRET,
      token: req.query.oauth_token,
      verifier: req.query.oauth_verifier
    };

    // Step 3. Exchange oauth token and oauth verifier for access token.
    request.post({ url: accessTokenUrl, oauth: accessTokenOauth });
```

Because the [node-request](https://github.com/request/request#oauth-signing) documentation describes Step 3 as:

```
 // step 3
  // after the user is redirected back to your server
  var auth_data = qs.parse(body)
    , oauth =
      { consumer_key: CONSUMER_KEY
      , consumer_secret: CONSUMER_SECRET
      , token: auth_data.oauth_token
      , token_secret: req_data.oauth_token_secret
      , verifier: auth_data.oauth_verifier
      }
    , url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
    ;
  request.post({url:url, oauth:oauth}
```

The difference is, in the satellizer example, it doesn't pass `token_secret` to sign-in, but it should. So is this a mistake or what am I missing?

The real problem for me was, 3 legged twitter sign-in flow actually requires `session` on server side, but the `satellizer` example doesn't use any sessions, so I was wondering how this possible without sessions, but either it is not possible and satellizer example is wrong, or I don't understand something.